# How to see AWS KMS events on AWS cloudtrail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail, amazon-kms

I am using AWS KMS to encrypt and decrypt some data. I want to track all KMS accesses using AWS cloudtrail. When I open my cloudtrail events page, I can't see KMS related events. On KMS [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html), it is mentioned that kms events are logged in cloudtrail.

Is there a setting to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

KMS is [not supported by](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events-supported-services.html) CloudTrail Event History.

However, you can see the KMS logs if you setup a trail:

> If you're looking for a specific API call that doesn't appear in the
>   event history, create a trail and check the log files in your S3
>   bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is no longer correct->

When a KMS key gets deleted, it goes through a scheduled key deletion period (7-30 days) and then gets deleted.

You can track the calls made on the `ScheduleKeyDeletion` and `CancelKeyDeletion` APIs through CloudTrail. After the waiting period ends, search in `CloudTrail` for `DeleteKey` .